# Logging user with sessions

Tags: php, session

This question might seem a bit imbecile but i really wanna know either i am doing it right or wrong.I have this website of mine that does require user login.Depends on the user if he want to log in to order something or just want to surf the website.Now , what i am doing is that whenever a user log in i make a session of the user instead of the cookies.I store the name , email of the user inside the sessions and i use those sessions as a check mechanism if someone has logged in.Now my questions are as follows:

**1)** Are sessions a safe mechanism to do all my authentication?

**2)** I have a page named *user_profile* that shows the user's profile such as *name*, *address* etc.I am using the email session variable to check for the corresponding email from the database and then display it on the *user_profile* page.Is this the correct way of doing it or should i pass email as *post* method from some other page?

**Note :**

**1.** I don't want to use any cookies.So please don't advise me to store cookies for the time being.

**2.** I have used *prepared statements* just to make sure my queries are sql injection proof(If not 100% Still less prone to sql injection)

Comment: sessions usually use session cookies, and the use of session cookies is recommended over use some query parameter like ?SID=...

Comment: Sessions will disappear when the user closes his browser, you want to store them in a db and use some hash method

Comment: yeah fine .Let the user log in again when he opens up his browser.But i wanna know is that is my way of doing things are right or wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably have better luck and more security storing your sessions against a unique hash instead of the email and username.

You can then store this unique hash in the database (or some other form of storage) against the username and email, that way securing your requests from potential data leakage in the event of some sort of hijack.

Something like the following would work:

```
$sessionId = hash('sha256', $username . $email . $timestamp . $salt);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, sessions can be hijacked; so it's not 100% safe. However, this is something you cannot prevent either; people can always fall victim to a phishing site. On a lighter note; you can store the users email and password in a session, then do a sql query everytime you're at a secure part of the site, and if the email and the password doesn't match in your database, you can run a session_destroy(); command and kills the session. (Which in turns redirects to the login page)

Comment: You shouldn't store passwords in sessions, presicely because of the reason you stated: session hijacking.

Comment: That's true, but if somebody hijacks your session it compromises your account regardless.